# py-3 | Trying to call a function based on an input doesnt work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input

*this is my problem :/*
[image]

So I 've been working in this project but I cannot find any answer to my question... why should I enter the letter C or c many times in order to call the c() function and sometimes doesn't even work? Is my script correct?

Script:

```
def c():
    print ('do something')

def s():
    print ('do something else')

def main():    
    if input() == 'S' or input() == 's':
        print ('Please enter the number you want to start with:')
        s()

    elif input() == 'C' or input() == 'c':
        print ('Please enter the number you want to check:')
        c()

    else:
        print ('Please enter either S or C')
        main()

print ('You want to Start with or Check a number? Enter S or C.')

main()
```

script result 1:

```
You want to Start with or Check a number? Input S or C.
c
c
c
c
do something
```

script result 2:

```
You want to Start with or Check a number? Input S or C.
c
C
c
C
Please input either S or C
You want to Start with or Check a number? Input S or C.
```

EDIT: I am sorry for the poor quality of the post but it's my first one!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include the source code as formatted text and a textual description of your problem. A screen shot is not sufficient.

Comment: `input() == 'S' or input() == 's'` asks for input twice if it’s not S. `input() == 'C'` asks for input a third time if it's not S/s. `input() == 'c'` asks a fourth time if it's not S/s/C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the input as the variable, and send that variable to the functions.

Like:

```
x = input('please enter a selection')
```

and then define your function

```
def s(x):
    print('you selected: ' + x)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! setting input() equal to a variable solved my problem!